Is there a Git native way to non-interactively transform a commit's metadata to produce a new commit without touching the working tree and index?
This is a generalization of my previous question, aimed at improving my understanding of what can and cannot be done internally to Git.
Suppose I have a commit A, and I want to change some arbitrary metadata, whether it is the parents, the tree, the author/committer, the author/commit date, the commit message, or the gpg signature, to produce a new commit B that shares all metadata with A except the bits I changed. Further, suppose my changes do not require creating a new tree; I am either using the original tree or substituting another existing tree.
I am currently aware of at least two ways to do this:

I can git checkout A and then use git commit --amend with various options. This is native to git and moderately flexible in terms of what can be changed. However, it is interactive and touches the working tree.
I can use git cat-file | <insert_sed_script> | git hash-object -w -t commit --stdin as this answer to my previous question describes.

The second way is semantically what I am looking for, but requires an external script that performs text manipulation on the text representation of a commit.
Is text manipulation the only current option for transforming commit objects non-interactively, or is there a more structured and semantic way to manipulate the commit metadata?

Example 1: Rather than writing a sed script that semantically says "delete the lines that start with parent and then insert new lines that start with parent", can I write a git command that says "set the parents of this commit to X,Y,Z" and output the commit with that change? (git replace can handle this case, but not the general case.)
Example 2: Rather than writing a sed script that identifies the commit message based on regexes and replaces it, can I write a git command that says "set the commit message of this commit to 'hello world'" and output the commit with that change?

Part of the motivation for asking this is intellectual curiosity; the other part is that I am considering building such tooling externally (by wrapping the text manipulation) if it does not already exist.

Do you want to "replace" the commit (i.e. updating all parent refs to point to the new commit or rather pretend that they point to the new commit, similar to git replace) or do you only want to manually create a new commit (existing commits will be unaware of the new commit)?

Just create a new commit, not update any parent refs.

Okay, then my answer provides a solution. The new commit will not be referenced by any other commit and starts "unreachable". You need to update a ref (branch, tag) to make it reachable.

git commit-tree creates commit objects from a tree. The commit message can be provided via stdin or -m option. -S/--gpg-sign allows to sign the new commit object. Set GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE to specify the author and committer time, respectively.
Example:
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Mer Lin' GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='mer@lin.com' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='2024-12-26T13:37:42Z' git commit-tree -p first-parent-of-the-new-commit -p optional-second-parent-of-the-new-commit -m 'This commit was created manually

Poviding multi-line commit messages
is straightforward.' -S your-gpg-key-id the-tree-id

To re-use/modify the message of an existing commit, feed it via stdin:
git show --format=%B old-commit | sed '...' | GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Mer Lin' GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='mer@lin.com' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='2024-12-26T13:37:42Z' git commit-tree -p first-parent-of-the-new-commit -p optional-second-parent-of-the-new-commit -S your-gpg-key-id the-tree-id

For instance, to append "Merry Christmas!" to your commit's message:
{
  git show --format=%B old-commit;
  echo 'Merry Christmas!';
} | git commit-tree -p old-commit^ old-commit^{tree}

If you need to copy over committer/author date/name/email from the original commit, populate the environment variables from the info obtained from the original commit:
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$(git show --format=%ae old-commit)" \
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$(git show --format=%an old-commit)" \
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(git show --format=%aI old-commit)" \
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$(git show --format=%ce old-commit)" \
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$(git show --format=%cn old-commit)" \
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show --format=%cI old-commit)" \
git commit-tree -p the-parent-id -m 'commit message' the-tree-id


git commit-tree is Neo for this Matrix.

After reading this answer, I believe that this approach will correctly "round-trip" a large fraction of the unsigned commits in the sense that we can reproduce an input commit exactly if we derive all the metadata from it.
However, it looks like commit-tree does not have a way of replicating all the possible headers explicitly if the source commit contained other headers.
Thus, if we wanted the ability to round-trip a source commit, I think we would need to revert to manually parsing the text representation and replacing pieces of it.

The approach described by this answer using commit-tree is likely sufficient for most practical uses, so I am merely noting that it does not round-trip commits with extra headers to prevent future confusion for myself and others.

@merlin2011 what extra headers are you talking about?

For now, they would be encoding and mergetag but the linked answer suggests that there's nothing preventing more from being added in the future.

To be more explicit about the possible confusion with round-tripping:
If I run git commit-tree using full data copied from the source commit (using the env vars in this answer), I might plausibly expect the resulting commit object to == the source commit. However, because commit-tree does not have an explicit way to specify the explicit "copying" of headers such as encoding and mergetag and any future headers from a source commit, the resulting commit  would not be exactly equal to the source commit.

Why might we care about this round-tripping? Usually when I'm testing the correctness of a piece of code that is intended to transform an input into an output based on changing specific parts of the input, the easiest way to convince myself that the code is correct is by asking the code the perform a "no-op" transformation and validating that the code was able to correctly replicate a variety of inputs. In this case, if the commit has no signatures and no other headers, invoking commit-tree with the env vars from the source would produce the expected output, but that is not 100% of commits.

@merlin2011 It looks like you want to pass the config option i18n.commitEncoding to have Git set the encoding header in the commit. The mergetag heaeder should be automatically created if you merge a signed tag. Note that if you recreate a commit that's 100% identical to the original commit, then your whole exercise becomes futile: you already have the commit that you are creating. The hash will be the same and so is the commit itself. What's the point in recreating the exact same commit again?

The point isn't to create the exact same commit; the point is to have confidence that the transformation process changes exactly what I want it to change and nothing more. :)

By way of analogy, suppose I wrote a sed script that replaces foo with bar globally in a text file. If there was no foo in the input, I would expect the script to produce an output that matched the input verbatim.

If I ran my sed script that is advertised to replace foo with bar on an input with no foo and it deleted all instances of the string alpha, I might think the script is buggy.

Another framing: using commit tree doesn't semantically copy a commit and modify the desired pieces; it's more we're explicitly picking the pieces that we want out of the old commit and creating a new commit from them. Given that the set of pieces can change, maintaining a copy and transform script based on commit tree requires writing bespoke code for each copyable header (signatures are of course not copyable if the commit actually changes) and then updating for new headers.
